# C# to lock or not to lock

Tags: c#, locking

Fearing I already know the answer. I have a class that handles services calls and caching. To avoid multiple calls to the service with the same request, I can of course use a **lock** around the code block *but* a lot of these methods have varying arguments which make up the cache key. It seems a shame to wait for a lock code block to execute when it could be for a completely different cache key (or multiple different cache keys).

I know I *could* do a lock on the cache key string itself but this is a no-no given that that string could potentially pop up anywhere.

So, I can either perform potential unnecessary calls to the service without the lock OR add potentially unnecessary delays within the method by waiting for the lock.

Are those my only 2 options or is there another?

Cheers

Comment: "To avoid multiple calls to the service with the same request, I can of course use a lock" - this sounds less than correct. A lock (System.Threading.Monitor.Enter/Exit) is used to mark a block of code that will be exclusively run by a single thread only for a given lock. It won't magically make repeated calls disappear. Please post a piece of code that the answer could be based upon.

Comment: @default.kramer You could do that, but you'd need to have a dictionary of those objects or something similar, so that you could find it again given another string.  You also need to be careful that your logic for determining what you need to lock on doesn't take more time/effort than just locking on everything (that will depend on the specific use cases, naturally).

Answer (score 7):

You could, potentially, switch your types around to use a thread safe class, such as a [`ConcurrentDictionary<T,U>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx), to handle your caching.  Used appropriately, this would prevent the need for locking (of your own), as you could rely on the fine grained locking built into the concurrent collection itself.